# Can I change the http response timeout in botframework?

Tags: botframework, httprequest, adaptive-cards, adaptive-dialogs

My bot logic includes a http request - GetFolderId.

[image: code sequence]

When I don't get a response within 15 seconds, the bot repeats every activity from the last response of the user to the http request and continues with the activities past that to end of the activity set. However I don't want it to do anything until I get the response.

The right sequence should be 1; 1.1; wait for the response; 1.2; then 2 and CancelDialog() OR continue with the rest based on the evaluation.

[image: chat]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5720

Comment: Hi Kyle, I am still not sure if this should be a question or an issue report, hence both the github post and the one here. If it's an issue I would ask if the developers can fix it, so the activity set doesn't continue to fire until it gets the response (as I believe it's the intended way). If I would be looking for a workaround, I would ask, how to make sure the dialog flow does not continue until I get the response from the http request. @KyleDelaney

Comment: @KyleDelaney Another possible question could be, since the bot does wait a little for the http response, is it possible to adjust this waiting time or is it wired?

Comment: Hi @AronGaborKelsch: It is expected behavior. If the bot operation takes more than 15 seconds, Teams service triggers retry. So, you will see duplicate calls and no option to change it.   Check following documentation if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: @AronGaborKelsch - Are you using Teams? Did Subba's link resolve your issue? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @AronGaborKelsch - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - Hi, as I see it now the pontentially long running task should be handled as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) I just wasn't expecting that http requests might fall in this category.